# Create Excel Add-in without VSTO

Tags: .net, com, vsto, excel-2007, add-in

I have used VS 2010 to create an Excel 2007 Add-in with C#. The add-in is a TaskPane-based UI. Works great, love it.

However, my users do not have Admin access and cannot install the add-in because VSTO is required.

Is there a way to create/port this add-in to a normal COM based add-in without this show-stopping reference to VSTO?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that your problem is that the add-in pre-requisites (VSTO runtime) require admin privileges to install?

Answer (score 1):

They shouldn't necessarily require admin rights just because you use vsto. Make sure that the addin is being installed "Per user" instead of "per machine".

Comment: I need admin to install VSTO on the machine. Excel otherwise doesn't recognize the .VSTO file that VS generates.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find anything definitive about installing the actual VSTO runtimes. I didn't think that it required Admin privs but I could be wrong. One question though. Is this a commercial product or an inhouse thing? If commercial, I'd highly recommend ditching VSTO altogether and going straight COM and IExtensibility2. If it's just an inhouse utility, you +should+ be able to roll out using one of the MS system admin tools or a third party rollout tool. VSTO is nice in some ways, but really, I think it causes just about as many problems as it solves.

Answer (score 1):

or you could package it up as .msi so that when users installed, it will be installed under system account.

even if you convert it to COM, you will have to register (regasm) the dlls and that requires admin rights anyway. Best not to go through COM route ... :)

Comment: You might have a point about still requiring regasm. I am, however, confused as to why you think that an MSI will help - won't that still require Admin credentials?

Comment: No, because when u run/install msi package it installs under system acc. Thats how we deploy to our users who doesnt have admin rights. Also we permission specific folder to make it easier to deploy xcopy based files