# VSTO addin and runtime without administrator rights

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto

I've developed a C# Excel Addin with Visual Studio 2008 (.NET Framework 3.5). My goal is to be able to install this Addin without administrator rights for Excel 2007. When I publish the solution, and try to install it as a non-admin user, the setup gives an error saying that VSTO runtime 3.0 needs to be installed:

> Prerequisite check for system component Visual Studio Tools for the Office system 3.0 Runtime failed with the following error message:
>   "Administrator permissions are required to install the Visual Studio Tools for the Office system 3.0 Runtime. Contact your administrator."

There is ZERO chance of getting an administrator to install the VSTO 3.0 Runtime on this network. .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is installed.

Before, I developed the Addin in VBA and was able to distribute it as a .XLAM.

This question is similar to: [Create Excel Add-in without VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707340/create-excel-add-in-without-vsto)

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Microsoft has gone to great lengths to develop a security model.  You mention there is ZERO chance, I have to ask, have you even tried asking?

Comment: I guess you don't understand the part about ZERO chance.

Comment: You can install your application, yet you cant install MS runtime? Im fairly certain you can package the runtime within your installer.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Shim add-in does not needs Admin rights